# How to display only videos from photolibrary in ios

Tags: ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on an iOS app. I want to selext some videos from iPhone library. I have done code as below but it also loads the photos from the photo library. My need is to load only videos on the device (not photos ONLY VIDEOS). So can anyone please help me what changes I need to for this goal? My code is as below:

```
UIAlertAction *Gallery = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Add Existing Video" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [alertcontroller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //VideoViewController *videoVC = [[VideoViewController alloc] init];

    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    //videoVC.sourceType = picker.sourceType;

    self.picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];

    NSArray *sourceTypes = [CustomCamera availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.picker.sourceType];
    //videoVC.pickerController = picker;
    if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie ])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"No Video available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Where do you actually create the image picker? That should be done only at the time you need it.

Comment: @rmaddy-you are getting my issue?what i need is picker should open only videos.currently it also show me the photo albums.

Comment: Yes, I know what you need. That's why I asked you a question which you didn't answer. Where do you actually create the `UIImagePickerController` instance? You need to create it in the code you posted in your question.